# Python Input validation - positive float or int accepted

Tags: python, validation, input

seems we are asking a lot, but we are seeking a short validation for positive int or float being entered as input. The code below rejects negative, text and null entries - yay! It accepts int as valid, but why doesn't entry like 1.1 pass? (seemingly a positive numeric entry) We want entry of positive 1 and 1.1 to pass. is there an easy way without two separate blocks, including try/catch?

```
bookPrice = input("What is the cost of your book? >> ")
while bookPrice.isnumeric() is False or float(bookPrice) < 0:
    bookPrice = input("Use whole # or decimal, no spaces: >> ")
bookPrice = float(bookPrice)
print("Your book price is ${0:<.2f}.".format(bookPrice))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

`isnumeric()` is checking if all the characters are numeric (eg 1, 2, 100...).

If you put a '.' in the input, it doesn't count as a numeric character, nor does '-', so it returns `False`.

What I would do is try to convert the input to **float**, and work around bad inputs.
You could've used [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), but for that you would need to convert the input to something else than **string**.

I came up with this:

```
message = "What is the cost of your book? >>"
while True:
    bookPrice = input(message)
    try:
        bookPrice = float(bookPrice)

        if bookPrice  <= 0:
            message = "Use whole # or decimal, no spaces: >> "
            continue
        currect_user_input = True

    except ValueError:
        currect_user_input = False
        message = "Use whole # or decimal, no spaces: >> "

    if currect_user_input:
        print("Your book price is ${0:<.2f}.".format(bookPrice))
        break
```